# Is there a way to make game with input text field and interact with the answer(createjs, AnimateCC) ?

Tags: createjs, easeljs, flash-cc

createjs is great but i think it is a bit limited in making a full game like put your name and lunch the game or answer specific question and then you can trigger an animation
i searched the web for this behavior in easeljs but no luck
the question is is it possible if yes can you provide an example
thanks

Comment: CreateJS is a framework for building animations, UI, and implementing audio. It is not a "game" framework that will provide all the functionality out of the box.

Comment: ok i did find a solution i will post a tutorial on it thanks

Comment: Please post the tutorial or some reference to the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Please share with us, thnks

Comment: hello i'm sorry for not posting anything and i think it'd for the best because the older solution i found is you need to modify your html file and use the dom with easeljs but today the solution has been implemented in the new version of animate cc 2017 they added the input text component
and you can find a code snippet to get the value and use it in your function, i hope this help :D